# Using variables from a function in another python program

Tags: python

So I'm trying to write a python program to integrate into a greater in-house developed python application. This program I'm writing needs to generate an xml document and populate the fields with data stored in variables from another function in a different module.

After realizing I can't have both programs import each other (main program needs to call xmlgen.py to generate the xml doc, while xmlgen.py needs to utilize variables in the main program to generate that doc), I'm a little bit at a loss as to what to do here.

In the example shown below, xmlgen.py needs to use variables from the function sendFax in Faxer.py. Faxer.py needs to call xmlgen.py to generate the document.

snippet from xmlgen.py:

```
from lxml import etree
from Faxer import coverPage, ourOrg, ourPhonenum, ourFaxnum, emailAddr, sendReceipt, webAddr, comments
from Faxer import sendFax

def generateXml():
    #xml file structure
    root = etree.Element('schedule_fax')
...
~ A bunch of irrelevant xml stuff
...

    grandchild_recipient_name = etree.Element('name')
    grandchild_recipient_name.text = cliName
    child_recipient.append(grandchild_recipient_name)
```

Now the piece of the main program I need to utilize the "cliName" variable from...

```
def sendFax(destOrg, destFax, cliName, casenum, attachments, errEAddr, comment, destName):
    creds=requests.auth.HTTPBasicAuth(user,password)

    allData=''
    allData+='<schedule_fax>\n'

    allData+='<cover_page>\n'
    allData+='<url>'+prepXMLString(coverPage)+'</url>\n'
    allData+='<enabled>true</enabled>\n'
    allData+='<subject>'+prepXMLString(cliName)+' - case # '+str(casenum)+'</subject>\n'
```

Now when I try to import sendFax function from Faxer.py, I'm unable to call any of the variables from the function like,

```
grandchild_recipient_name.text = sendFax.cliName
```

does not work. What am i doing wrong here?? I'm not a python guru and am in fact quite new to all of this, so I'm hoping it's something simple. Should I just dump everything into a new function in the main program?

Comment: Fundamentally, you misunderstand how local variables work. Local variables are accessible *only inside the function*. They are not available as *attributes on that function* (although functions can have attributes, but that isn't really relevant). The standard way to access data you need from a function is to return that data from a function, so `return some_var` and then in the caller, `result = my_func()` and now `result` will reference whatever is returned.

Comment: What if you run the python file including functions from the main python file ?

Comment: Guys, thank you for the input. I am not a coder by trade... just a lowly net admin trying to pick up the pieces when our software guy quit lol. But, I'm learning a lot and I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed out above, you are trying to reference cliName as if it is an attribute of the function. This would be closer to being correct if sendFax was a class, but that's another subject. The snippet you have provided is simply a function definition. It doesn't guarantee that this function is ever actually used or give you any idea what cliName actually is, cliName is just the name used by the function internallt to describe the 3rd value supplied as input.

What you need to do is find where sendFax is actually used, rather than where it is defined. Then look at what the variables are called which are passed into it. There are two ways to pass variables into a function: by position and by name. If the variables are being passed by pposition you will find something like:

```
sendFax(some_name,some_other_name,yet_another_name,...
```

The third one of these will be the variable which becomes cliName inside the function.

If being passed by name you will see something like

```
sendFax(cliName=yet_another_name,...
```

Where once again yet_another_name is the thing which becomes cliName.

Depending on how the programme is structured you may be able to refer to yet_another_name from your program and get the value you need.

```
from Faxer import yet_another_name
```

But this will only work if Faxer runs and finishes with the one and only value of yet_another_name assigned. If Faxer iterates through lots of values of yet_another_name, or simply doesn't run sensibly when called as an import you'll need a more sophisticated approach.

Comment: Thanks so much for this information. As I said above I'm not a coder but a network admin trying to resolve issues after our programmer left. But I appreciate the help and I am learning a lot. That being said, I did figure out on my own that my approach was all wrong shortly after posting this. I essentially did as you instructed and found where "sendFax" is used in the main program

Comment: def sendFax(self, job):
        Faxer.sendFax(job.destOrg, job.destFax, job.cliName, job.casenum, job.files, job.staffEmail, job.comment, job.destName)

Comment: so what I tried to do is create a new function in the main program to send those same variables to the xmlgen module, createxml function, but it sill doesnt seem to run. I simply modified the sendfax function to send the same variables to my xmlgen module lol

Comment: def createXml(self, job):
        xmlgen.generateXml(job.destOrg, job.destFax, job.cliName, job.casenum, job.files, job.staffEmail, job.comment, job.destName)